# Can this function return an int value by linking the elements of a list?

Tags: python, function

I am creating a function in order to develop a tiny word game. When I was creating it I got stuck when I tried to write the body. I was looking for information about Python and if I can write a return statement . It seems that it is possible but I didn't find out anything clear about that. This is my body function: This is my current progress: Am I close? or Should I try another method?

```
def num_words_on_board(board, words):
    """ (list of list of str, list of str) -> int

    Return how many words appear on board.

    >>> num_words_on_board([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], ['ANT', 'BOX', 'SOB', 'TO'])
    3
    """
    count = 0
    for word_list in board:
        if words in ''.join(word_list):
            count = count + 1

        return count
```

Comment: You need to explain more what your game is suppose to do. HOWEVER, it looks like your return statement is likely indented too far. The way it's currently implemented, it will only look at the first word in `board`

Comment: Your `if` statement appears to be asking if a list of words (`words`) is in the string resulting from joining a different list of words into a string; is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Yes! Couldn't agree with you more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a function return an int value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944449/can-a-function-return-an-int-value)

Comment: yes, we are a team, but no one can help us in this question... even when we get all stuck at the same point.

Comment: @user7491985 in the words you want to find on the board, can the letters appear in any order or just the regular one? Please give a more explained example and specify the goal of this code better.

Comment: just in the regular form. Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking in explanation, but I'll answer the best I understood.

I think you are trying to do something like a wordsearch solver, mixed with a scramble puzzle?

Anyways, my recommendation is to make multiple functions for everything you need to solve. For example:

The way I see it, you need to know if the letters in the `board` can make up each of the words in the `words` variable. That can be done by one function. If you don't really need the order of the word, just the length, then we can do it like this.

```
def same (word, letters):
    temp = []
    for every_letter in word:
        if every_letter in letters and every_letter not in temp:
            temp.append(every_letter)

    return len(temp) >= len(word)
```

This function takes only one `word` and a "bunch of `letters`" (for example a list from `board` ;) ) as parameters, then the function compares each letter in the `word` against each letter in the "bunch of `letters`" and  if it finds a match it adds it to a `temp` variable, at the end of the iterations if the temp variable has at least the same count of letters as the initial `word' then it's safe to say that the word can be built.

*there is a problem with this function. If the original `word` has repeated letters, for example the word "butter" then this function will not work, but since this is not your case we are good to continue.

For the second part we have to use that function for every `word` in `board` so we'll use another function for that:

```
def num_words_on_board(board, words):
    count = 0
    for word in words:
        for letters in board:
            if same(word, letters):
                count += 1

    print(count)  # This is not needed, just here for testing.
    return count
```

And there we go. This function should return the `count` which is `3`. I hope this helps you.

(if anyone wanna correct my code please feel free, it's not optimal by any means. Just thought it would be easy to understand like this, rather than the answer in the duplicate question mentioned by Stefan Pochmann)

:)

Answer (score 0):

I had a previous function can I use it in order to create this new one?.
My previous function is this:

def board_contains_word(board, word):
    """ (list of list of str, str) -> bool

```
Return True if and only if word appears in board.

Precondition: board has at least one row and one column.

>>> board_contains_word([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 'ANT')
True
>>> board_contains_word([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 'NNT')
False
>>> board_contains_word([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 'NTT')
True
"""
for word_list in board:
    if word in ''.join(word_list):
        return True
return False
```